# giving to object velocity to the direction it facing (unity)

Tags: unity

I making 2d game on unity5 .I want to give to an object starting velocity to the direction it is facing(looking).(I put it in the "start" method)
how can i do it?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the character/sprite you're trying to move? Depending on what you're doing, you might have a different definition of "facing direction" - eg. a spaceship in a Tyrian style shooter usually faces up, while a platformer character usually faces right, but can sometimes turn around to go left...

Comment: Do you want it to always travel in that single direction, even if it rotates to point a new direction later (for any reason)?

Comment: i instantiated a 4 balls with random rotation I want that every ball will get starting velocity,to the directiin it facing.but if the ball will collide it will change the velocity direction according to the colliding(the velocity is-starting velocity-)

Comment: But what is the "facing direction" of a ball? Is it the local x, y, or z axis?

Comment: only the z axis,the other are 0

Answer (score 1):

Well, on **DMGregory's** pointing, I did realize that you want this work done in 2D. So, I did some work on this, here I'm pasting the code which should be attached to your object which you want to accelerate.

Here are some assumptions I made,

- Your object is not child. (Otherwise it will be not a big deal though, you have to play with `+ 90` factor)
- Your object should have attached `Rigidbody2D`.
- Wrote this script with getting input from keyboard. Do change it according to your needs.

Code,

```
// Rotation Speed
public float _rotationSpeed = 1;

// Speed
public float _velocity = 1;

// Attached Rigidbody2D
Rigidbody2D _rb;

void Start ()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

void Update ()
    {
        // Getting input from keyboard (w,d / Left arrow,Right arrow)
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        // Applying rotation according to inputs
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z - (horizontalInput * _rotationSpeed));

        // Getting angle which will help to move object to forward
        // + 90 is the factor as 2d sprites have z rotation of -90 degrees while it look visually as angle with 0 degrees. PLay with it if your object is child of another.
        float theta = transform.localEulerAngles.z + 90;

        // Getting new X direction
        float newDirX = Mathf.Cos (theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        // Getting new Y direction
        float newDirY = Mathf.Sin (theta * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        // Applying velocity according to current angle
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2 (newDirX, newDirY) * _velocity;
    }
```

I wrote it in hurry, if you still find any problem then let me know

Comment: OP mentioned that they're making a 2D game, in which case they'll likely want [Rigidbody2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) instead of the 3D version. Interpreting the "facing direction" is a bit tricky in this case, since transform.forward points along the local z axis, which in 2D games is often into/out of the screen. For a side-scroller, transform.right might be correct, while for a spaceship in a vertical shooter, transform.up might be appropriate.

Comment: Sorry man, my bad. I was on mobile device, let me correct it

Comment: @DMGregory can you endorse it? :)

Comment: I'll pass. I usually try to avoid trigonometry-based solutions where simple vector algebra will suffice.

Comment: But they use to be more interesting :)

Comment: there is no way do that without sin and cos?

Comment: Believe me it more than easy. Paste code as it is. It will work

Comment: You right it works!

Comment: :) Good to listen that, told you bro :)

Answer (score 0):

We want to simulate wind resistance.

There is some restoring torque $\tau$ that will align your velocity $\vec{v}$ with your attitude $\vec{a}$ (where *attitude* is the direction you are pointing, and *you* means the projectile.

A torque pointing into the page will push youe body clockwise, and out of page will push your body counter-clockwise.

$\tau = k_{air} * \vec{a} \times \vec{v}$ will push the projectile's attitude to line up with its velocity. Where k is a number you make up that makes the projectile swing at an acceptable rate.